# OS X / CUPS how to get originating host of print job?

Tags: macos, cups

I need to distinguish between local and remote CUPS print jobs on the server side.
I thought the originating host of the print job can be used, but I could not find a way to reliably get its value, the closest thing is one of the IPP job attributes "job-originating-host-name", but when I check with "ipptool" for a paused job printed from one host to another it is empty. "lpq" reports the same job as "localhost", so not very helpful too.

This is for a custom CUPS backend part of virtual OS X printer , but if you know anyway to get this information it might help, thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that the reason for "job-originating-host-name" not showing is that it is one of the [default private job attributes](https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.6/ref-cupsd-conf.html).
Changing JobPrivateValues in cupsd.conf makes it visible, e.g. replace it everywhere in cupsd.conf with "JobPrivateValues none".